# Laravel fortify 2FA code does not expire after 30 seconds

Tags: php, laravel-8, fortify, google-2fa

I'm working on a new laravel 8 project using jetstream and when testing laravel fortify's two-factor authentication the codes expire after 1 minute; In the google authenticator app the codes always expires after 30 seconds.

I scanned the QR code with the Google Authenticator app and created the project with the command

> laravel new test --jet

and selecting livewire as jetstream stack

How can I change the duration of the code to expire in 30 seconds?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks @Ron I have made changes that I hope conforms to a reproducible example.